# Best place to keep singleton instances

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, singleton

Where is the best spot to store instances of singleton classes?
Say for instance I have a configuration class (which loads global settings for the application), and perhaps a class that accesses a web service, I am not sure where the best spot to instantiate these, and to keep them.

Currently, I have them as instances of the Program class (where Application.Run is called from), and it seems to work fine, but I am unsure if thats the best method!...

```
static class Program
{
    public static string dbConnectString = "Data Source=" + 
        Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + 
        @"\xxx.sdf" + ";Persist Security Info=False";
    public static Settings settings = null;

    [MTAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        settings = Settings.Instance;
        Application.Run(new MainMenu());
    }
}
```

And throughout the application, I am calling it like this:

```
txtWebServiceUrl.Text = Program.settings.getSetting("web_service_url");
```

Is there anything wrong with this, or what is the best method?
Thanks!

Comment: I usually create an static class named Context, and put them there.

Comment: `Settings.Instance` seems like a fine enough "place" for the instance. It's created there and accessed through that property getter. Clear and concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the point of the Singleton pattern. You don't store a reference to Singletons as there is intended to only be a single reference, controlled by the Singleton.

The pattern works in that anywhere you need to use the Singleton, you reference it through it's single Instance, in your case: Settings.Instance.

Singletons themselves are a bit of a smell in that by nature they break Inversion of Control, making code more difficult to test. In legacy applications where I've run into Singletons and Static Classes I tend to modify them to extend an interface. (I.e. ISettings) which exposes the desired behaviour, then utilize something like a lazy-load dependency into the classes that want to access it:

```
private ISettings _settings;
public ISettings Settings
{
  get { return _settings ?? Settings.Instance;}
  set { _settings = value; }
}
```

This allows your tests to substitute the settings with a stub/mock. It defaults to the Singleton. It's an effective, lightweight re-factor that enables some testability in code that relies on Singletons and Statics.

Comment: Wow not sure how I overlooked this. Great reply!

Answer (score 3):

I personally would make 'em nice and easy to get to - putting 'em in a 'Settings' or 'Global' class.  Oh, and if possible I'd have properties [or enum] to access the settings rather than a string key so intellisense can bash you over the head when you make a typo.

```
public static class Settings
{
    static Dictionary<string,string> data = new Dictionary<string,string>();

    public static string WebServiceUrl {get {return data["web_service_url"];}}
}
```

Used like so:

```
 txtWebServiceUrl.Text = Settings.WebServiceUrl;
```

Though obviously this is optional.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi. That has definitely giving me some ideas! Although it doesn't really help my original question as to where to store these instances.

Comment: I'd still store them in a 'Global' or 'Settings class' - the idea of properties is just an extension of that.